# Python. ".readline", ".readlines" methods issue. How does it work

Tags: python, methods

Don't understand (passing task on Coursers) how the second code can read the file content. Without **".readline"**, **".readlines"** methods.
Can't run the first.
Task (The file contains lines of words, need to count quantity of words)

```
#the first
file = open('/Users/max/Desktop/education/Test_record.csv', 'r')
num_words = 0
for lines in file.readlines():
    line = file.split()
    num_words += len(line)
print(num_words)
#file.close()


#the second (runs well)
num_words = 0
fileref = "/Users/max/Desktop/education/Test_record.csv"
with open(fileref, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        num_words += len(line.split())
print(num_words)
#file.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out this article about asking good questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
It is pretty much impossible for us to help you without sharing any actual code

Comment: Why is for loop indented?

Comment: You should do is ```lines.split()``` in first one.

Comment: Why? I do that when do loop iteration the lines

Answer (score 1):

Your first sample *could* work, it only contains an error since you define a `lines` variable then try to call `split` on `file`, not on `lines`. It is however a bit redundant, cause you first read all lines in memory, then iterate over them.

The second sample is the standard way to do the job: you iterate over the file lines while reading them.

Comment: I understood my mistake, tried split a file, but must to do that operation with lines, line = file.split()-----> line_s = line.split() But still don't understand how the second code read the file, without read method

Comment: It's a builtin feature of the file object. From the Python tutorial: "For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code". The `readline()` method can be useful when you want more control, perhaps read a single line or whatever, but for simply looping over all lines the iterator capability of the file object is the best option. The `readlines()` has its uses too, although since it brings all the contents in memory it must be used with care when dealing with large files

Comment: There are two ways to do it because `readlines()` was the original way to do it in Python 1, before it was possible to iterate over files. File objects became iterable in Python 2.

Comment: gimix,  BoarGules thank you so much guys for explaining